# Does Chilkat support temporary file name during FTP, FTPS and SFTP uploads?

Tags: chilkat

Our software uses the Chilkat library to upload files using FTP, FTPS and SFTP.  Some of these files are large and take time to complete the upload.  Does Chilkat support using a temporary file name  (e.g. file.filepart) while uploading large files to prevent the receiving system from trying to take the file until is has been uploaded and renamed to it's final name (e.g. file.xml)?

If it does, how do we enable this functionality?  Also, does this functionality require a disconnect/connect before the renaming is done?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for Chilkat to bake into the API a feature for it.

The various functions that do uploads have arguments such that the local filename and remote filename are separate.  You can set the remote filename (i.e. destination/target filename) to a temporary filename, and then after the upload you can call the appropriate function to rename/move the file to the final filename.

Comment: Our code is currently doing that (upload then rename).  I was just wondering if Chilkat has a "baked in" feature in the API that would handle this behind the scenes.